# Why is this piece of code not returning anything except the headers?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

Trying to run this piece of code on DBPEDIA and it doesn't return anything except headers.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?diseasename ?personname where {
 ?disease a dbo:Disease .
 ?person dbo:deathCause ?disease .
 ?person rdfs:label ?personname FILTER (lang(?personname) = "en").
 ?disease rdfs:label ?diseasename FILTER (lang(?diseasename) = "en").
 ?disease rdfs:label ?diseasename FILTER (?diseasename = "Brain tumor")
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `FILTER (?diseasename = "Brain tumor"@en)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?diseasename ?personname where {
   ?disease a dbo:Disease .
   ?person dbo:deathCause ?disease .
   ?person rdfs:label ?personname 
      FILTER (lang(?personname) = "en").
   ?disease rdfs:label ?diseasename 
      FILTER (lang(?diseasename) = "en").
   ?disease rdfs:label ?diseasename 
      FILTER (?diseasename = "Brain tumor"@en)
}
```

-- or, noting the redundancy in the query pattern above, this --

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?diseasename ?personname where {
   ?disease a dbo:Disease .
   ?person dbo:deathCause ?disease .
   ?person rdfs:label ?personname 
      FILTER (lang(?personname) = "en").
   ?disease rdfs:label ?diseasename 
      FILTER (?diseasename = "Brain tumor"@en)
}
```